# delete array from nested object array in javascript on more than one conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
days[
    {
      dt:2017-06-19T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:1,
      releases:[],
    },

    {
      dt:2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:2,
      releases:[{
               id:41,
               programId:2,
               teamId:116,
            }]
    },
    {
      dt:2017-06-21T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:3,
      releases:[]
    },
]
```

i want to delete the releases that have an id of 41 AND day.id of 2.. so my array should look like :

```
days[
    {
      dt:2017-06-19T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:1,
      releases:[],
    },

    {
      dt:2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:2,
      releases:[]
    },
    {
      dt:2017-06-21T00:00:00.000Z,
      id:3,
      releases:[]
    },
]
```

i have tried to filter :

```
var found = days.filter(function(day){
           return day.releases.filter(function(r){
                          return r.id===41
            });
 });
```

and then get the index and remove from there but i know there's a simpler way to do this.. can anyone help? There can be more than one releases in the nested releases object array so i need to specifically remove by looking at the release id and also the days id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate `days` and filter only the releases which have the wanted `id`.

```js
var days = [{ dt: '2017-06-19T00:00:00.000Z', id: 1, releases: [], }, { dt: '2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z', id: 2, releases: [{ id: 41, programId: 2, teamId: 116, }] }, { dt: '2017-06-21T00:00:00.000Z', id: 3, releases: [] }];

days.forEach(function (day) {
    if (day.id === 2) {
        day.releases = day.releases.filter(function (release) {
            return release.id !== 41;
        });
    }
});

console.log(days);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Excatly what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use `.map` javascript prototype function to achieve this as follows-

```js
var days = [
    {
      dt:'2017-06-19T00:00:00.000Z',
      id:1,
      releases:[],
    },

    {
      dt:'2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z',
      id:2,
      releases:[{
               id:41,
               programId:2,
               teamId:116
            }]
    },
    {
      dt:'2017-06-21T00:00:00.000Z',
      id:3,
      releases:[]
    }
];

days = days.map(function(object){
      if (object.id === 2){
            object.releases = object.releases.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id !== 41
            });
      }
      return object;
});

console.log(days);
```

Comment: thanks! i want the current array to be changed. however the code works !